# How can I decrypt a message with RSA if $e = 65536$ and $\gcd(e,\phi(N)) = 8$?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, prime-numbers, decryption

In a message exchange with RSA, an unusual public exponent $e = 65536$ is used.
Since $N$ is easily factored, I am able to derive $p$ and $q$. Consequently $ \phi(N) = (p-1)*(q-1)$.
However, since $2^3$ is present among the factors of $ \phi(N), \gcd(e,\phi(N)) = 8$. It is not possible to compute the private exponent d directly.
I tried to reduce the problem to the calculation of $d = (\frac{e}{8})^{-1} \mod \phi(N)$, from which I would have obtained $M^{8} = C^d\mod N$.
I don't think this is the correct solution, because since $e$ is a power of two, $ \gcd((\frac{e}{8}), \phi(N)) = 8$, so we are right where we started.
Am I a bit off road?

Comment: Since $e$ is even, that's not [RSA](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr) per se. Hint: since you have $p$ and $q$, solve the problem modulo each of these and then combine the solution(s) by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(constructive_proof)). Since $e$ is even, $M^e=C\bmod p$ is equivalent to $\bigl(M^{e/2}\bigr)^2\bmod p$ and we know [how to solve that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) for $M^{e/2}\bmod p$. That can be applied several times.

Comment: HINT: There is more than one possible solution to $M^8= C^d\mod N$, but not too many more.

Comment: [This paper by Daniel Shumow](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1059) covers this precise scenario.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks a lot, I was able to find the right solution!

Comment: @Jake: glad you worked it out. I gave hints rather than a detailed an answer because this look like a CTF / challenge / homework. But if you determine that's ethical, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @Jake could you share your solution? I'm doing a similar thing but i'm struggling to find the solution.

Comment: @Jake - for the sake of others please answer your own question and then tick it.